# How can I configure Webpack (or Babel) in order to use sass in a React project?

Tags: reactjs, webpack, sass-loader

As from the title, I don't know where to start configuring anything in order to be able to use **.scss** files for my components.
I know how to configure loaders in **webpack.config.js**, but in the boilerplate I have, there is no **webpack.(dev|prod).config.js**

I've read that I should create a **.babelrc**, but then I got lost.
Can anyone help me with this?

structure of my project:
[structure folders of project](https://i.stack.imgur.com/PlPSE.png)

Comment: Looks like it is a project generated from create-react-app. If it is there is guide how to add scss here https://github.com/facebookincubator/create-react-app/blob/master/packages/react-scripts/template/README.md#adding-a-css-preprocessor-sass-less-etc

Comment: Yes, it's a project generated from create-react-app. Thank you!
In order to use "svg-sprite-loader",  do I need to run eject and add the setting in webpack config or there is a better way to do so?

Comment: If you need to modify webpack config and use custom stuff then you need to eject. Once you eject, you can't go back. Personally I would backup first to make sure I could go back in case something is broken or don't work as expected.

Answer (score 1):

You'll need to install a few loaders with `npm`:

`npm i style-loader css-loader sass-loader --save-dev`

Then you'll need to add the loaders to the `module` section of your webpack config file:

```
module: {
  loaders: [
    // Sass
    {
      test: /\.scss$/,
      loader: 'style-loader!css-loader!sass-loader'
    },
    // CSS
    {
      test: /\.css$/,
      loader: 'style-loader!css-loader'
    }
 }
```